# To list the files changed by sed while inserting new line

Tags: shell

I want to insert a new line in a file using `sed` command and finally want to list the files modified by sed  command

```
sed -i "s#^\([[:space:]]*\).*$after.*#&\n\1$new#" $path/*.yml
```

This command insert a new line after a given pattern in a list of files now I want to know the list of files inserted by sed command

```
sed -i "s#^\([[:space:]]*\).*$after.*#&\n\1$new#" $path/*.yml

sed -i "s#^\([[:space:]]*\).*$after.*#&\n\1$new#" $path/*.yml
```

This command insert a new line after a given pattern in a list of files now I want to know the list of files inserted by sed command based on the given pattern

Comment: I used > and tee command to redirect it creates only empty file, Is there any other way to get the list of files changed by sed while inserting or deleting a line in a file

Comment: I think it will be easier to 1. scan your files, to see which ones need the change, create a list from that,  2. make the change 3. run a 2nd scan to be sure the changes have been made. `grep -l "srchTarg" files*` will get your step 1 (and 3). Good luck.